# CreateRestrictedToken( ) from WinAPI

Tags: windows, winapi, token, sandbox

My question is about WinAPI `CreateRestrictedToken( )` function.

How can I create token that allows process to initialize and start itself, but restrict access to **all** files on computer, except some specified files?

Obviously we should enable logon SID in this token (to let the process use window station). But I'm a bit confused with `SidsToDisable` and `SidsToRestrict` from that function. Their usage is not clear to me.

The plan was to start process with only logon SID enabled, and then grant permission to logon SID for some files. But it seems it does not work. So I'm stuck, and really need help.

Comment: What version of Windows? If you're running Windows 8+, you can/should use AppContainers: https://www.malwaretech.com/2015/09/advanced-desktop-application-sandboxing.html

Comment: The question is about tokens. "My question is about WinAPI CreateRestrictedToken( ) function."